# Upload files in chunks - asp.net and IE9

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer, fine-uploader, plupload

We have looked at different jquery multi file upload plugins for our asp.net web application. The main feature we are looking at is sending files to server in chunks.

We will be targeting IE9 and firefox browser.

FineUploader has very good features but doesn't support IE9 for file chunks.  PLUpload is also good but don't know if it supports file chunk for IE9.

Is it possible to chunk files by Implementing IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest in handler? IE9 doesn't support file chunk via API but can this be done through http handler?

Comment: `files[]` + `Parallel.ForEach` seems good to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Files cannot be split into chunks browser-side unless the browser supports the File API. IE9 does *not* support the File API. You could perhaps use a flash, silverlight, or client-side Java solution, but these are all technologies to be avoided.

Comment: what is the difference b/w file API and chunk via flash / silverlight?

Comment: on our server file size limit is set to 1GB so do we really need to use chunk?

Comment: We're getting a bit off-topic here, but you never _need_ to chunk files. But if you can, you should, especially with large files, such as those above 100 MB. 1 GB is a huge file to upload.